# Count the number of numeric keys in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using PHP 5.6, and I have the following array:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => James
        )
    [1] => Array (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Tim
            [children] => Array (
                    [0] => Array (
                            [id] => 4
                            [name] => Sam
                        )
                    [1] => Array (
                            [id] => 5
                            [name] => Florence
                        )
                )
        )
    [2] => Array (
            [id] => 3
            [name] => Stephen
        )
)
```

I'm trying to find a neat and fast way to count the number of people, which is the same as counting the number of numeric keys, which should be `5`.

```
echo count($myarray); // 3 (only first level)
echo count($myarray, COUNT_RECURSIVE); // 16 (every key/value)
```

Is there a good way to do this with built-in PHP functions, or do I need to traverse the whole multidimensional array and count them manually..?

**EDIT** My array could end up being 1,000+ people (or more), with many many levels (an unknown number of levels).

Comment: Is there a reason that you can't just walk through it with a for loop?

Comment: @kainaw, a for loop would have to recurs through the array many time, like the function in my answer :P

Comment: I could, but my array could end up being 1,000+ people, with many many levels (an unknown number of levels), so I'm looking for a neater way.

Comment: @CrusaderLtd, has my answer helped you at all or do you need something else?

Comment: count() just counts keys. it doesn't care WHAT those keys are, or they represent. it has no filtering functions. if you want to count only numeric keys, you'll have to build that yourself. e.g. `preg_grep('/^\d+$/', array_keys($arr))`, but that doesn't do recursion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is important to note that, even if there were a PHP built-in (such as `count($myarray, COUNT_RECURSIVE_NUMERIC);`) internally, it would still be traversing the whole array, recursively.  If you are worried about Out Of Memory errors, try pass-by-reference, which will not copy the array or the array items:

```
define('COUNT_RECURSIVE', 1);

function count_numeric_keys(&$array, $flags = 0) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $count += (int) (is_numeric($key));
        if ($flags & COUNT_RECURSIVE && is_array($value)) {
            $count += count_numeric_keys($value, $flags);
        }
    }
    return (int) $count;
}

$count = count_numeric_keys($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
```

Mayhaps?

Comparison with non-pass-by-reference, type-hint, and small benchmark:

```
define('COUNT_RECURSIVE', 1);

function count_numeric_keys(Array &$array, $flags = 0) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $count += (int) (is_numeric($key));
        if ($flags & COUNT_RECURSIVE && is_array($value)) {
            $count += count_numeric_keys($value, $flags);
        }
    }
    return (int) $count;
}

function count_numeric_keys_np(Array $array, $flags = 0) {
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $count += (int) (is_numeric($key));
        if ($flags & COUNT_RECURSIVE && is_array($value)) {
            $count += count_numeric_keys_np($value, $flags);
        }
    }
    return (int) $count;
}

$tpl_array = array(
    1=>"one",
    "two"=>"two",
    3=>array(
        1=>1,
        "two"=>2
    )
);

// Fill the array with both numeric and non-numeric
$array = array();
for($i = 1000; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $array[] = $tpl_array;
}

for($i = 1000; $i > 0; $i--) {
    $array["not a number $i"] = $tpl_array;
}

echo "Pre Memory: ".memory_get_usage(TRUE).PHP_EOL;
echo "Count: ".count_numeric_keys($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE).PHP_EOL;
echo "Reference Memory: ".memory_get_usage(TRUE)." current, ".memory_get_peak_usage(TRUE)." peak.\n";

count_numeric_keys_np($array, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
echo "No-Reference Memory: ".memory_get_usage(TRUE)." current, ".memory_get_peak_usage(TRUE)." peak.\n";
```

View it on [IDEONE here](https://ideone.com/YYMfkQ).

ODDLY, having a reference on `$value`, like `foreach($array as $key => &value) {}` actually increased memory usage.  Bizarre...

Comment: pass by ref.. you should do the same with the $count var and just do $count++;

Comment: Thanks Mike... Any mileage is using `array_walk` rather than `foreach`..?

Comment: Less overhead in foreach, array_walk is cleaner for applying strictly callbacks, also, it would prevent the counting bit without additional overhead.

Comment: Just a note, I re-edited my edit.  The Flag adds minimal overhead, and I added a type-hint.  IDEOne is up to date.

Answer (score 1):

I just created this recursive function to do this for ya :P

```
function countNumericKeys($array)
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        if (is_numeric($key))
        {
            $count ++;
        }
        if (is_array($value))
        {
            $count += countNumericKeys($value);
        }
    }
    return $count;
}

// Test it!

$array = [
    1=>"one",
    "two"=>"two",
    3=>[
        1=>1,
        "two"=>2
    ]
];

print countNumericKeys($array); // Output: 3, correct (in this case at least)!
```

Shortened the code so it uses ternary operators instead of the `if`s that it was :P

```
function simpleCountNumericKeys($array)
{
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $value)
    {
        $count += is_numeric($key) ? 1 : 0;
        $count += is_array($value) ? simpleCountNumericKeys($value) : 0;
    }
    return $count;
}
```

**TEST USING `array_keys`** -- only gets the top level keys of the array

```
function countArrayKeysNumeric($array)
{
    $count = 0;
    $keys = array_keys($array);
    foreach ($keys as $key) $count += is_numeric($key) ? 1 :0;
    return $count;
}

$array = [
    1=>"one",
    "two"=>"two",
    3=>[
        1=>1,
        "two"=>2
    ]
];

print countArrayKeysNumeric($array);
```

Prints 2... :(

Comment: Thanks Sam, that obviously works, however I was looking for a different way (other than traversing the whole array). I guess `count($myarray, COUNT_RECURSIVE_NUMERIC);` would be perfect, but doesn't exist.

Comment: @CrusaderLtd, as far as I know, there (as you say), isn't a way to do this in PHP by default, so a custom wrapper which iterates through the array is the best way (I'm sure PHP would do the same thing)

Comment: @CrusaderLtd, the other way would be to use `array_keys` and loop through that, but that again is not recursive through all the parts (AFAIK), see the test at the bottom of my answer

Comment: @CrusaderLtd, may I ask why you do not want to iterate through the whole array? (Seems like a bad idea because without traversal/iteration you are not going to get all the arrays that are nested counted)

Comment: i dont think recursive function is good for very large arrays. you will soon get out of memory errors.

Comment: Just because of the size that the array could end up being, and the number of (unknown) levels. Just thought there might be a better way. Thanks for the `array_keys` update, that's probably the best solution!

Comment: @Umingo, without recursion how will you walk through each item of the array? `$array[0]; $array[0][0];` and so on?

Comment: @CrusaderLtd, beware with `array_keys`, it **does not** recurse through the whole array if there are more arrays within, it only gets the top level array (in your example array, 3)

Comment: @SamSwift웃 Of course, you took the recursion out, I'll use a recursive function with ternary operators. :-)

Comment: @CrusaderLtd, hope it goes well for you :P